# Getting Row /multiple Row data in datagridview when checkbox is checked using c#

Tags: c#, xml, checkbox, datagridview

Hi I would like to ask a solution where i can get the whole row data or multiple rows from a datagridview if the checkbox is checked and save it to an xml file

here is my exisiting code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = ds.Tables["Tables"];
  DataView view = new DataView(dt);
  view.RowFilter = "MD_ID = " + MdNum;

  //add checkbox to datagrid data
  dataGridView2.Columns.Add(chk);
  chk.HeaderText = "Select";

  //populate datagridview with data
  dataGridView2.DataSource = view;
}

private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

my table has 4 columns MD_Num, MD_ID, MD_AGE, MD_DATE. is it possible to select a row and insert each value of the column to an individual textbox and save it to an XML file with the ff format:

```
<MDS>
  <MD> 
      <Tables>
         <MD_Num>VALUE#</MD_Num>
         <MD_Num>VALUE#<MD_Num>
         <MD_AGE>VALUE#<MD_AGE>
         <MD_DATE>VALUE#<MD_DATE>
      <Tables>
  <MD>
</MDS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question... 
inside the cell click event for the dataGridView

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtnum.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["MD_Num"].Value.ToString();
        txtid.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["MD_Num"].Value.ToString();
        txtage.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["MD_Age"].Value.ToString();
        txtdate.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["MD_Date"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

for the save button, feel free to change the path of the xml file

```
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string num = txtnum.Text;
        string id = txtid.Text;
        string age = txtage.Text;
        string date = txtdate.Text;

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Details.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.WriteStartElement("MDS");
        create_node(num, id, age,date, writer);           
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("XML File created ! ");
    }
```

then the method you will have to add that creates the nodes

```
  private void create_node(string num, string id, string age,string date, XmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Table");
        writer.WriteStartElement("MD_Num");
        writer.WriteString(num);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("MD_ID");
        writer.WriteString(id);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("MD_Age");
        writer.WriteString(age);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("MD_Date");
        writer.WriteString(date);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

ooh and under the `InitializeComponent()` change selection mode to full row select

```
 dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```